# Varibles in taurus yaml

Tags: yaml, load-testing, taurus, bzt

We're preparing a yaml taurus file to run a load test with taurus. This load test will include several scenarios, with a common ramp-up and hold-for time.

We've the following code:

```
- concurrency: 5
  ramp-up: 60m
  hold-for: 60m
  scenario: scenario1
- concurrency: 8
  ramp-up: 60m
  hold-for: 60m
  scenario: scenario2
- concurrency: 9
  ramp-up: 60m
  hold-for: 60m
  scenario: scenario3
-
  .....
```

Is there a way to define the time for the ramp-up and hold-for in a variable in the yaml file (not in external file)? To don't have to repeat it for each scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for [JMeter Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like:

```
modules:
  jmeter:
    properties:
      ramp-up: 3600
      hold-for: 3600
```

Once done you can amend your scenarios to use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like:

```
- concurrency: 5
  ramp-up: ${__P(ramp-up,)}
  hold-for: ${__P(hold-for,)}
  scenario: scenario1
- concurrency: 8
  ramp-up: ${__P(ramp-up,)}
  hold-for: ${__P(hold-for,)}
  scenario: scenario2
- concurrency: 9
  ramp-up: ${__P(ramp-up,)}
  hold-for: ${__P(hold-for,)}
  scenario: scenario3
```

More information:

- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [JMeter Properties and Variables](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#JMeter-Properties-and-Variables)